# iOS Segue - When are the viewControllers Instantiated

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, segue

I have a simple storyboard with a Main View Controller and two Detail view Controllers as shown in the diagram.

**Question #1** - Where is the code that SequeA will present DetailA located

**Question #2** - In my code for the AppDelegate I need to create an array of all the ViewControllers that are in the App - How can I get that array? - It is in the story board but how do I programmatically access it.

I can get the MainViewController by doing the following - 
    myViewControllerMain = (ViewControllerMain*) self.window.rootViewController;

but I don't know how to access the detail view controllers (a & b)

**Question #3** - Is DetailA instantiated when the the MainViewController is instantiated or is it instantiated when the Seque is "triggered" (what is the right word here - Called?)

[image: StoryBoard with MainViewController and Two Detail Views]

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1

Comment: I have looked at the rayWenderlich link.  There is a reference there to get to the main view controller - but I already know that.  AFAIK - It does not address how to get to the other view controllers.  Since I am not using a Navigation Controller - there has to be something in the storyboard that tells me what all of the other viewController are.

Comment: I'll add an answer as there isn't space in the comments

Comment: I've tried to answer your questions below, but I have to confess that the questions, themselves, raise issues. Why do A or B need to know a list of view controllers? Can you explain what you're trying to do? I might infer that this is a candidate for custom container view controller on the basis of your questions (which is a very different topic than all of us have answered), but you'd have to explain in greater detail what the master is doing, what A and B are doing, etc. Can you describe the workflow or business logic in less abstract terms? We'll be able to offer more constructive advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You asked:

> **Question #1** - Where is the code that SegueA will present DetailA located?

If you're invoking segue A programmatically (e.g. calling `performSegueWithIdentifier`), that code is in the master view controller. Often, though, you don't need to invoke it programmatically at all, because when you create the segue in Interface Builder, you're often linking it from some control, like a button in the master view, and thus you don't have to do anything programmatically to initiate the segue. When you invoke segue A, though, the optional associated `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier` (for iOS 6 and higher) and `prepareForSegue` are called in master view controller.

> **Question #2** - In my code for the AppDelegate I need to create an array of all the ViewControllers that are in the App - How can I get that array? - It is in the story board but how do I programmatically access it.
>
> I can get the MainViewController by doing the following -
>
> ```
> myViewControllerMain = (ViewControllerMain*) self.window.rootViewController;
> ```
>
> but I don't know how to access the detail view controllers (a & b)

Generally you don't need to maintain arrays of view controllers (with the possible exception of custom container view controllers, and even then, sometimes you don't have to do it yourself). But, if you need to access some property of your app delegate, you can do something like:

```
YourAppDelegate *appDelegate = (YourAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
// you can now access properties of the `appDelegate`
```

Having said that, I'm hard-pressed to think of situations where its advisable for Detail Controller A or Detail Controller B to be retrieving a list of view controllers from the master. You really should explain what business problem you're trying to solve. Generally you'd do some delegate protocol or use some notification process. It varies based upon the problem you're solving. But you should take a hard look at your design if A or B needs to get a list of view controllers from the master.

> **Question #3** - Is DetailA instantiated when the the MainViewController is instantiated or is it instantiated when the Seque is "triggered" (what is the right word here - Called?)

With the exception of custom containers and/or embed segues, the basic process is:

- the segue is triggered;
- `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier` is optionally called in iOS 6, if `NO` then we stop here;
- the destination controller is instantiated;
- `prepareForSegue` is called, allowing you to pass information from the source controller to the destination controller;
- the view associated with the destination view controller is then created;
- `viewDidLoad` in the destination is called (the take home message being, don't try to manipulate the views/controls in this destination view prior to this point, such as in the source's `prepareForSegue`);
- only then will the destination view complete its layout, appearance calls, etc.

---

#### References:

- [View Controller Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457) is a good overview of storyboards, view controllers, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response.
Is there a way I can get a list of SegueIdentifiers.  

In the storyBoard my MainView is Connected to ViewA via a Segue.  In InterfaceBuilder that segue has been provided with an Identifier which is a string.  

I would like to NOT hard code that string in my code but just check if Segue "X" was invoked.  Segue X is an object - why should I rely on a string to inquire what Seque was invoked.

Comment: @OneGuyInDc There is no persistent Segue X object. Anyway, `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier` and `performSegueWithIdentifier` _only_ have identifier strings so there's nothing else for you to use. And the `UIStoryboardSegue` object in `prepareForSegue` is re-instantiated every time you perform it, so you can't compare those. The `identifier` is the advised technique. The other approach would be subclassing the segues and looking at class membership, but that's a lot of extra work and significant loss of readability with no real benefit.

Comment: When does DetailViewControllerA or DetailViewControllerB get "destructed"? (Sorry for my C++ roots)

In other words In DetailViewControllerB I have a button which when clicked does a  

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];

Does the above line destruct the DetailViewControllerB.  I don't think that is happening.

Comment: @OneGuyInDc Assuming that you're not maintaining strong references to these controllers elsewhere, a view controller is deallocated when you call `popViewControllerAnimated` or `dismissViewControllerAnimated` (as depending upon whether you used a push segue or modal segue, respectively). You can verify this by writing your own `dealloc` method for your two controllers, e.g., `- (void) dealloc { NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__); }` If you do this, you controller will tell you when it's be deallocated. (By the way, I'm assuming you're using ARC.)

Comment: dealloc is not being called -  how will the following create strong ref
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"analog"]) {
        ViewControllerAnalog *vca = segue.destinationViewController;
        vca.AnalogVoltageA  = myAnalogVoltageADataPoint;
        vca.AnalogVoltageB = myAnalogVoltageBDataPoint;

    }
    else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"temperature"]) {
        ViewControllerTemperature *vcb = segue.destinationViewController;   
        vcb.TemperatureDataPoint = myTemperatureDataPoint;
    }
}

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23807/discussion-between-rob-and-oneguyindc)

Comment: So what happens for embed segues?

Comment: @fatuhoku The process is very similar, except that the embed segue is performed automatically as the parent view is instantiated, rather than being performed as a result of some user interaction.

Answer (score 1):

1) If you hooked it up in IB, there is no code (other than the XML file that describes the storyboard).

2) You can't get access to the other controllers until you instantiate them.

3) It's instantiated when the segue is performed.

Why do think you need to create an array of all your controllers in the app delegate?

Answer (score 1):

If you read the link, you will understand that there is no code to perform the segue as you asked . . . the XCode / Interface Builder) is not a code generator as you may understand it if you have use interface builders in other languages, it is not writing code for you, so there is none to be found. That being said, you can programmatically call a segue.

As for listing out the ViewControllers, I don't believe there is a way to do this in the manner you're hoping. ViewControllers are just classes of a particular type. The only thing you could do is to get a list of all classes loaded and iterate though checking if they are view controllers, but this would be slow and I'm not sure why you would want to do it, after all the only way this code would be executed would be to be included in your project and surely you know what code you have in your project?

View controllers are instantiated when the segue is performed.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification - I am coming from the .Net/C# and this concept is slightly different.