# Why does my view in a Navigation Controller clear after hitting the back button?

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, navigation

I have two UITableViewControllers in a navigation controller with static cells that I am using for my form. I have a show segue from a cell on the first view to the second view, but when I hit the back button on the second view, all of the data in the text fields and pickers in the second view is erased. Why is that and how can I fix it?

Comment: Show the code of the cleared view controller.

Comment: Theres nothing interesting, just a standard UITableViewController.

Comment: A standard table view controller does not delete all the cell data.

Comment: It's not the data in the cells, but the text fields and switches. I think that it is creating a new version of the second view controller every time, instead of switching back and fourth. I could be wrong though.

Comment: Ah, I see, the _second_ view controller is the problem. Yes, the second is re-created and not reused. Just implement deinit in the second view controller with a basic print("deinit called") and you can check this by yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it didn't quite work. The deinit is called, but the view is still reloading. I did a little further research, and it seems that there might be a strong connection between my static cells and my view. I haven't defined any outlet between them, so I am confused as to why this may be. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second view controller is created every time you perform the segue from the first to the second view controller. Therefore the initial state of the second view controller is re-created every time new. See this answer to understand the process better (It's the answer to question 3):

[iOS Segue - When are the viewControllers Instantiated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14607581/ios-segue-when-are-the-viewcontrollers-instantiated)

You have many options to resolve this. E.g:

- store the data in the second view controller on disk (e.g. with NSUserDefaults) and re-create if every time the view controller is created
- store an instance of the second view controller in the first view controller and do not segue to it but call `self.navigationController?.pushViewController` to open the second view controller
- etc...

Comment: I'll probably end up using the first option, but the second option requires me to create a new instance of the second view controller. Am I doing this wrong, or should I just use the first method?

Comment: With the second option you would reuse the once created instance every time. But go for option one if you like this more.

Comment: I got the second method working, I was creating a new instance every time instead of as a class variable. Thank you so much for your help, I really appreciate it. I don't have enough reputation to up vote your answers yet, but I will when I can.